# Check if source exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss

I'm writing a website in Rails and I need to reed a RSS feed. The script works as intended, but I just got an error indicating that the source could not be read.

This is the script:

```
def setup_feed
  source = "http://path_to_feed/"
  content = "" # raw content of rss feed will be loaded here

  open(source) do |s|
    content = s.read
  end
  @rss = RSS::Parser.parse(content, false)
end
```

My concern is that the site will produce an error or just "crash" if the source isn't available for whatever reasons. How can I protect myself against this?

This is the exact error:

```
Errno::ENOENT in WelcomeController#index

No such file or directory - http://path_to_feed/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
Found a more recent link: http://binarysoul.com/blog/rails-3-url-validation by Eric Himmelreich

```
class Example
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  ##
  # Validates a URL
  #
  # If the URI library can parse the value, and the scheme is valid
  # then we assume the url is valid
  #
  class UrlValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
      begin
        uri = Addressable::URI.parse(value)

        if !["http","https","ftp"].include?(uri.scheme)
          raise Addressable::URI::InvalidURIError
        end
      rescue Addressable::URI::InvalidURIError
        record.errors[attribute] << "Invalid URL"
      end
    end
  end

  validates :field, :url => true
end
```

Comment: I couldnt get the URI parser to work, but i added the rescue bit and it seems to take care of the error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'll want to handle external requests like this in the background.

It's a bit too involved to provide a simple example here, but the main steps are:

1. Create a model to store the data from your feed
2. Write a rake task to perform the request, and save the result into your model
3. Setup a cron job to run the rake task periodically
4. Display the contents of your model on the page

This way, page loads are dependent only on your own database, not on any external resources that you may not control.

Comment: Thanks Tobias, ideally that would be what i would do and i will probably do it later, but it was kind of an urgent task, so i had to do a quick fix for it. Ill keep your advice in mind so i can implement it later.